# HTMLMediaPlayer in UNO always return BLANK or undefined ontimeupdate event

Tags: html, uno-platform

I am trying to catch the progress of playing video, basically need to capture currentTime of video.
I am always getting Blank if using isDetailJson : true and undefined if false.

This HTMLMediaPlayer usage was referred from CH9 as suggested by UNO team.

```
public HtmlMediaPlayer()
        {
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);

            this.RegisterHtmlCustomEventHandler("timeupdate", OnStateChanged, isDetailJson: true);      
        }

        private void OnStateChanged(object sender, HtmlCustomEventArgs e)
        {
            var js2 = $"alert({e.Detail});";
            this.ExecuteJavascript(js2);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.RegisterHtmlCustomEventHandler` is designed to work with a [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) payload. [Documentation here](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/wasm-custom-events.html)

The [`timeupdate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event) event is generating a payload of type `Event` (wihtout anything useful in the even itself).

A right fix for your problem would be to inject the following javascript code:

### JavaScript

```js
// 'element' is the video tag
element.ontimeupdate = () => {
  const payload = {currentTime: element.currentTime};
  element.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("newCurrentTime", {detail:payload});
};
```

### C#

```cs
this.RegisterHtmlEventHandler("newCurrentTime", OnStateChanged, isDetailJson: true);
```

> ### How it works internally
>
> When the `isDetailJson` is set to `true`, the framework will serialize the `CustomEvent`'s payload (`.Detail`) into a JSON string. See the [code here](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/1814717cf22b094ae93e322d5c49d2e36e620d7f/src/Uno.UI/ts/WindowManager.ts#L1080).